# Apache Camel as HTTP proxy: how route to URL with parameters

Tags: http, proxy, apache-camel

I am trying to use Camel as HTTP proxy and I am following the example from Apache Camel itself:

```
  <route>
    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/myapp"/>
    <to uri="jetty:http://realserverhostname:8090/myapp?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
  </route>
```

Question: what if the URL in the destination should look like the following:

```
<to uri="jetty:http://realserverhostname:8090/myapp/something?parameterdId=1232345?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
```

Looks like the extra "?" in the URI makes the bridgeEndpoint not to be seen, any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not use more than one question mark in URL. First parameter should be separated by question mark and all subsequent with ampersands (&) which you should probably escape in your config file, so it should look something like:

```
<to uri="jetty:http://realserverhostname:8090/myapp/something?parameterdId=1232345&amp;bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
```

Comment: Yes the URI was invalid. You need to use &amp; to separate when you use 2+ parameters. Also consider using throwExceptionOnFailure=false to rely back any http errors directly in the bridge. Its also what we suggest on the Camel documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That should do the trick :) ! I also added your suggestion (but I was just taking 1 step at a time ;)).